# Facebook Custom Login Sample button name is not appearing in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, uistoryboard, facebook-sdk-3.1

I have followed the following Facebook Custom login sample from git hub

https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-howtos/tree/master/FBLoginCustomUISample

they have used XIB instead of that i have used Storyboard.

every thing is working perfectly but the button name is not appearing.

If any one knows the solution to sort this issue please help me out
Thanks in Advance.

My code:

AppDelegate.M

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  ViewController  *ViewObj = [[ViewController alloc]init];

    self.ViewObj = ViewObj;

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
        NSLog(@"Found a cached session");
        // If there's one, just open the session silently, without showing the user the login UI
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info"]
                                           allowLoginUI:NO
                                      completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                          // Handler for session state changes
                                          // This method will be called EACH time the session state changes,
                                          // also for intermediate states and NOT just when the session open
                                          [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                                      }];

        // If there's no cached session, we will show a login button
    } else {
        UIButton *loginButton = [self.ViewObj btn_LoginAction];
        //[loginButton setTitle:@"Log in with Facebook" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [loginButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"login_FB.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }


    return YES;
}

- (void)userLoggedOut
{
    // Set the button title as "Log in with Facebook"
    UIButton *loginButton = [self.ViewObj btn_LoginAction];
   // [loginButton setTitle:@"Log in with Facebook" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [loginButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"login_FB.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // Confirm logout message
    [self showMessage:@"You're now logged out" withTitle:@""];
}

// Show the user the logged-in UI
- (void)userLoggedIn
{
    // Set the button title as "Log out"
    UIButton *loginButton = self.ViewObj.btn_LoginAction;
    //[loginButton setTitle:@"Log out" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [loginButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logout_FB.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // Welcome message
    [self showMessage:@"You're now logged in" withTitle:@"Welcome!"];

}
```

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn_LoginAction;
```

ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender
{
    // If the session state is any of the two "open" states when the button is clicked
    if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen
        || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended) {

        // Close the session and remove the access token from the cache
        // The session state handler (in the app delegate) will be called automatically
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

        // If the session state is not any of the two "open" states when the button is clicked
    } else {
        // Open a session showing the user the login UI
        // You must ALWAYS ask for basic_info permissions when opening a session
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info,email"]
                                           allowLoginUI:YES
                                      completionHandler:
         ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

             // Retrieve the app delegate
             AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
             // Call the app delegate's sessionStateChanged:state:error method to handle session state changes
             [appDelegate sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
         }];
    }
}
```

my Simulator Screen

[image]

Comment: Please ecplain your problem a little bit clear...

Comment: Sure Aman Aggarwal. Which part of my explanation is Not clear?

Comment: button name is not appearing but you are giving image to your button at the time of login and logout

Comment: yes even image is also not appearing. I tried both string and image its not working i don't know what mistake i did in that

Comment: why don't you try setting the image or text of the button in xib and check if it is working...

Comment: Also try logging `loginButton` and check if it is nil or the button instance you require is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try following Code for set button image :

// Login

```
[loginButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"login_FB.png"]
forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

// Logout

```
[loginButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logout_FB.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

We need to setBackgroundImage for set title of button not use setImage.